# HttpTunneling a TCPClient application

Tags: c#, tcpclient

We have a custom chat application(c#) which uses TCPClient. We are having problem on clients who are behind Firewall or proxy. We know that these client can browse the internet without a problem so we decided to change our TCPClient application so that It uses HTTP messages to communicate.

Will it be enough just to wrap our text massages with standard HTML tags and HTTP headers? We need a long lasting connection. Does keep-alive have a limit? Do firewalls or proxies have time limits for "alive" connections.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "decided to change our TCPClient application so that It uses HTTP messages to communicate"? Are you sending "fake HTML-pages" for example? Or are you talking about SOAP? Or do you just connect to port 80 as that seems to be allowed? Also what do you mean by "wrap our text messages with standard HTML tags"? Something like `<p>myText</p>`? In general, keep alive should not be a problem but long lasting HTTP connections might well "feel strange" to network infrastructure at some point (but that does not have anything to do with keep alive itself).

Comment: I am planning to wrap our messages with html tags like <html>our message</html> so that it appears like it is a web page.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to change your protocol, probably pretty significantly. There's no guarantee that a proxy is going to use the same TCP connection for subsequent HTTP requests, it has the freedom to close any connection after receiving a message from the server, and they generally will after only a few idle seconds.

Unless your protocol can work stateless, then it isn't going to work over HTTP through a proxy.

Comment: himm... our chat application needs an open connection and our server differentiates clients by their sockets then we will need to implement something to track state of clients.

Comment: Chat applications over HTTP (well, pretty much all applications over HTTP) us a cookie or token to keep track of clients that is passed to the client on the first connection and stored in a local database.

Another thing to keep in mind is that with HTTP only the client can initiate a connection. The server can't "push" anything down, only respond to requests. So you'll need to use a polling mechanism.